# Aurelia binding: property-getter called repeatedly

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm currently learning and using Aurelia and something kind of weird (maybe normal) is happening.

When using the following code

```
export class NavBar {
  get username() {
    console.log('o_o')
    return 'name' + Date.now()
  }
}
```

And in the template `${username}`, the username is always updating, several times per seconds (and console.log are logged several times as well of course).

The workaround is to simply use a function and not a getter and call `${username()}` in the template. But is this behaviour normal? So should I use sometimes getter sometimes not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is normal, Aurelia polls your property for changes because it has no way of knowing when your property-getter will return a different value.

If it were a simple property (without a getter), Aurelia could observe the property directly, no polling would be needed.

To avoid the polling you could tell Aurelia's binding system what to observe:

```js
import {computedFrom} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Foo {
  _username = 'hello';

  @computedFrom('_username')
  get username() {
    return this._username;
  }
}
```

Another option would be to use a one-time binding:

```html
${username & oneTime}
```

Comment: I forgot about the one-time binding, and didn't knew about the `computedFrom`. Thanks a lot for your explanations!